# In a flowing layout design in InDesign how I might full fill the spaces left at the end of the pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign, white-space

[image]

As you can see at the left, there is a lot of white space at the bottom of the page 1. My boss doesn't like it and forces designers to put "enters" (new lines) between the paragraphs in order to full fill the page more evenly (as in the right). Doing this will broke the automatic system of InDesign because if something is added later and there will be no white space, then it will create white where it should not be (because of the white space).

You have to notice that this is done with flow, it means that content flows thought the pages, sometimes up to 16 pages, so it's very probable to change something and white spaces will changes again. Then some design should look around the whole document to remove the new lines created.

Is there any way to automatically fill a page in InDesign?
thanks

Comment: Don't ever use "enters" to achieve this. Add a new text container and flow the text into by re-sizing the previous container in the chain. Similarly in word processing documents, many people use line breaks to get to the end of a page when they should be using a hard-page break (or a conditional one if available).

Comment: why is there space? A graphic? An image? Just white space? There are steps to create wraps around graphics and you can anchor object inline to make them flow with text.

Comment: the space in the "present" is because the content on page 2 is too long to fit into the page 1, therefore flows on page 2.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make an empty rectangle and wrap the text around it as if it were an image.This would act as the spacer and your text would continue on its merry way...

Comment: I cannot understand very well how to do what you said, can you elaborate a little bit more? thanks

Comment: If you make a box at the full width of the page, any text would wrap onto the next line. You would then adjust your box object height to control the gap. Here is how to make the text wrap: http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-wrap.html

Comment: but this will not provide me with the benefits of flowing text. What's the difference between spaces and warping in this way? If changes happens I still have to manually remove and re-size the rectangles to keep the spaces...

Comment: Besides it being easier to remove or adjust the height, there is not much difference. I'm really not sure what you are asking for. I thought you were after a method to manipulate where the white space sat on the page while keeping multiple pages flowing .

Comment: Yes, but by not losing the InDesign flow text feature (which means no manual checks after changes). And yes, your suggestion is better than spaces.